# What causes the SML error: Exception- InternalError: asGenReg raised while compiling

Tags: sml, polyml

I am learning SML, and couldn't figure out why the following textbook code generates an error:

```
fun  recip (x,y) = let val t = x *x + y *y in (x /t, ~y/t) end;
```

The error is:

```
Exception- InternalError: asGenReg raised while compiling
```

This is with Poly/ML 5.7.1.

The code computes the reciprocal of a complex number `(x,y)`. I tried adding `;` and parentheses at places to no avail.

Strangely, the following changed (incorrect) definition works without any error.

```
fun  recip (x,y) = let val t = x *x + y *y in (x, ~y/t) end;
```

The error message is not very informational.

*Can someone help explain where the error is and how to fix it?*

Comment: This compiles fine with MLton 20180207.  So this looks like a polyml bug.

Comment: "Internal" errors are bugs in the language implementation; there is pretty much nothing you can do about it. Try updating polyml (it's at 5.9 now). If that still doesn't work, consider posting an issue on their github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments @qouify and @mobdnilo pointed out, this error seems to be a bug of the particular version of PolyML in Ubuntu. I reinstalled the PolyML by compiling from source to the latest version (5.9), and the error is gone.